# linux mkdir directory in directory

Tags: linux, mkdir

I need to make a hierarchie of directories but I can only use 1 command, how can I do the following?

I'm currently in the directory called 'linux', now I have to create here a directory called 'a' and in this directorie I have to create a directory called 'b'.

thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
mkdir --parents a/b
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir -p a/b/c/d

-p      Create intermediate directories as required.  If this option is not specified, the full path prefix of
         each operand must already exist.  On the other hand, with this option specified, no error will be
         reported if a directory given as an operand already exists.  Intermediate directories are created with
         permission bits of rwxrwxrwx (0777) as modified by the current umask, plus write and search permission
         for the owner.
```